# ExpressJS with MySQL - PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm, protocols

I have an ExpressJS server with Node, running with the [MySQL npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), and all works fine. However, when I leave the server running a long time (say, overnight), I always come back to it having crashed, stating `PROTOCOL_PACKETS_OUT_OF_ORDER`. (See below)

How can I fix this, if even at all, as this server is soon to be deployed to production and this will be impossible if it crashes every night.

```
node:events:505
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: Packets out of order. Got: 0 Expected: 17
```

Comment: You can try to change from createConnection to createPool. Feel free to read through this https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2534. Or you can try foreverjs.

Comment: @TitanXP Thanks - I'll try `createPool` and see if that works! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem but after I have changed from createConnection to createPool, it won't crash already.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const con = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 5,
  host: "localhost",
  user: // your user,
  password: // your password,
  database: // your database,
  debug: false
});

con.on("connection", connection => {
  console.log("Database connected!");

  connection.on("error", err => {
        console.error(new Date(), "MySQL error", err.code);
    });

    connection.on("close", err => {
        console.error(new Date(), "MySQL close", err);
    });
});

module.exports = con;
```